# [SymmetricDS]: sym_node update conflict on PRIMARY KEY

Tags: symmetricds

I have multi tier sync node HQ > REGION > STORE

When I install new node for STORE, and register it to REGION, it is successful. 
But at HQ, I not able to see the new node for STORE...

At REGION outgoing batch and HQ incoming batch, I see below error on 'config' channel

> Detected conflict while executing UPDATE on hq.dbo.sym_node.  The
>   primary key data was: {node_id=001}. Failed to fallback.  The original
>   error message was: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK__sym_node__5F19EF16369E5FC6'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.sym_node'. The duplicate key value is (001).

The problem is I don't even have this record in my HQ table, why is it complaining ?
Can anyone help me to understand ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to register two sites with the same external ID 001. Lookup the file symmetricds.properties of all the stores searching for one sharing the same external ID

Comment: No this is a new node id. I try uninstall few times, the same error will appear once it is successfully registered

Comment: run command symadmin uninstall. My region > store is ok, From region > HQ came out this error,

Comment: Understand. Could you configure the external ID if the site with a completely new value?